# Mysql COUNT, GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sql-order-by, substr

This sounds quite simple but I just can't figure it out.

I have a table `orders` (`id`, `username`, `telephone_number`).

I want to get **number of orders from one user by comparing the last 8 numbers** in `telephone_number`.

I tried using `SUBSTR(telephone_number, -8)`, I've searched and experimented a lot, but still I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Untested:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS cnt,
    *
FROM
    Orders
GROUP BY
    SUBSTR(telephone_number, -8)
ORDER BY
    cnt DESC
```

The idea:

1. Select `COUNT(*)` (i.e., number of rows in each `GROUP`ing) and all fields from `Orders` (`*`)
2. `GROUP` by the last eight digits of `telephone_number`<sup>1</sup>
3. Optionally, `ORDER` by number of rows in `GROUP`ing descending.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *If* you plan to do this type of query often, some kind of index on the last part of the phone number could be desirable. How this could be best implemented depends on the concrete values stored in the field.

Answer (score 1):

//Memory intensive.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE REGEXP `telephone_number` = '(.*?)12345678'
```

OR

//The same, but better and quicker.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` WHERE `telephone_number` LIKE '%12345678'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to get last 8 characters from a column values.

select right(rtrim(First_Name),8)  FROM [ated].[dbo].[Employee]